# Passing a directive to directive via an object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

Lets say there are 2 directive components 
 1) **List**
 2) **Profile**

"List" should accept the data in the form of  Object notation passed to it through the controller and display the HTML or Directive components in the form of List. For example

```
var obj =[
{
component ://profile directive something like <Profile name="Shehzad" age=29/>
},
{
component ://news directive something like<News content="Headlines" />
}
];
```

And the Profile directive contains the following UI
`<div>`
`<div> name is {{name}}</div>`
`<div> age is {{age}}</div>`
`</div>`

Similarly News directive will contain the following UI
`<div>`
`<div>{{content}}</div>`
`</div>`

I want the List component to read the "obj" and render the Profile and news directive in a List view. Can anyone plz explain how the above thing can be achieved in angularjs

Here is the plunker link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/I1kJhYCqMkSD2qFIUQo8?p=preview

EDIT: plunker to show how to add directive dynamically like asked http://plnkr.co/edit/U88iPk?p=preview

Comment: what you posted isn't valid JSON, but it appears that what you want to do is have an expression that when evaluated is another angular construct that would then be compiled, which won't work.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's never a good idea to store UI elements in data.

Comment: theoretically all you need to do is nest the directive, but since you didnt put any code at all nor the exception how can we help? put it all in a plunker and post it

Comment: its not storing the UI elements in data, but increasing the flexibility of reusing the components. In ReactJS this thing is a breeze. I hope there is a way to get it working. What other alternative way do you suggest of achieving the same without passing via an object.

Comment: @bresleveloper here is the link of sample plunker code http://plnkr.co/edit/I1kJhYCqMkSD2qFIUQo8?p=preview

Comment: see new plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/U88iPk?p=preview

Comment: dude i cant program it all for you, i gave you all the tools

Answer (score 0):

you want to use directive in other directive, so add it on List directive view like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="profile in profiles" >
<profile name="{{profile.name}}" age="{{profile.age}}" ></profile>
</div>
```

Comment: Then this code gets tightly coupled only to profile and List. I will not be able to reuse this code for other components like news, messages, weather etc. From the above piece of code what exactly i want is the profile component to be dynamically injected into list. so that any other component can be used in the list .

Comment: So try use ng-transclude - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/I1kJhYCqMkSD2qFIUQo8?p=preview this is plunker sample scenario. see how we can fix this using ng-transclude